# Can someone mention the puranic source of Navgraha mantra?

Tags: puranas, astrology, vyasa

For example, the mantra for Surya is the following one -

> Japakusum Samkasam Kashyapeyam Mahadhyutim
> Tamoarim Sarvapapaghnam Pranatosmi Divakaram

Like this one there are mantras for nine planets. These mantras are used in Jyotisha for Graha Shanti. As far as I know, these are part of Navgraha Stotram composed by Vyasa. I read that these are Puranic Mantras. In which Puran Navgraha mantras are found. Please mention the verse numbers.

Comment: Where did you read that they are found in Puranas?

Comment: One of the scholar in Vedic astrology Sanjay Rath mentioned in his book that these mantras are Puranic Mantras written by Vyasa. https://www.amazon.in/Vedic-Remedies-Astrology-Sanjay-Rath/dp/8170822459